# Is it necessary to regenerate the 'dhparam.pem' file every time I renew my certificates?

Tags: nginx, openssl

I have a website with nginx.

I have installed ssl certificates successfully. I must renew these certificates.

My question is:
Is it necessary to regenerate a 'dhparam.pem' file (using 'openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096')?
Or is it enough to just install the new certificates and keep the old 'dhparam.pem'?

Thank you very much.

I'm not sure what I have to do.

Comment: No, (FF)DHE params are not linked to the cert and don't need to be regenerated. In fact in most environments since about 2015 you don't need them at all; most things have switched to ECDHE instead of (FF)DHE. And if/when you and your users move up to TLS1.3, it never uses configured dhparams -- it rarely uses FFDHE at all and when it does it uses fixed rfc7919 groups. You _usually_ should regenerate the privatekey, although it is technically possible to get a new cert for an existing privatekey. But these are not programming or development questions.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219349/is-there-a-benefit-to-diffie-hellman-parameter-rotation and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116479/regenerating-dhparam-periodically

Comment: Thanks very much, dave_thompson_085